# Unexpected output using hashing

Tags: algorithm, hashtable

Hello everyone lately I encountered quite an easy algorithm problem which at my great surprise I encountered a difficulty. The task was to return true if a particular array contained a duplicate element else false
Actually I don't understand why my program produces an **unexpected output** . I know many other solutions to solve that problem but I want to understand why this solutions doesn't not work . And it returns **False** from input **[1,2,3,1]**
In facts it's always returns false nor matter the input. It never passes the condition in the try statement

```
       dic = {}
        for i in range(0,len(nums)):
            try:
                if dic[nums[i]]:
                    return True
            except:
                dic[nums[i]] = i
        return False
```

Comment: Please edit your question by including your code, the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: @Bashful Beluga . The code is edited with a code snippets

Comment: what is "nums" /

Comment: Hello @Sarthak nums is the input list of numbers

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't always return `False`. It would return `True` if your duplicated value is  NOT  at the start of `nums` (which I assume is a list of numbers).

Notice that on line `dic[nums[i]] = i` on the first iteration you are updating your dictionary with `i` equals to 0. That is why later on you can't catch the case in which your duplicated value is at the start of the list.

Comment: Thanks bro I didn't realize at each first iteration I was actually mapping my key  to a falsy value